# How to use a generator inside an openhook in a fileinput object?

Tags: python-3.x, io, generator

I try to replace all the tabulation characters by 8 whitespaces in a
`fileinput` structure by using the `openhook` argument of the
`fileinput` class.

Here is my current source code:

```
from io import TextIOWrapper

class IterStream(TextIOWrapper):
    """
    File-like streaming iterator.
    """
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.generator = generator
        self.iterator = iter(generator)
        self.leftover = ''

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterator

    def next(self):
        return self.iterator.next()

    def __next__(self):
        return self.iterator.__next__()

    def read(self, size):
        data = self.leftover
        count = len(self.leftover)
        try:
            while count < size:
                chunk = self.__next__()
                data += chunk
                count += len(chunk)
        except StopIteration:
            self.leftover = ''
            return data

        return data[:size]

    def readline(self, size):
        return self.read(size)

    def readlines(self, size):
        return self.read(size)

    def close(self):
        pass

def streamfilter(filter):
    def stream(iostream):
        return IterStream(filter(iostream))
    return stream

@streamfilter
def tab_filter(stream):
    for line in stream:
        yield line.replace ('\t', ' ' * 8)


def fileinput_hook(filename, mode):
    return tab_filter(open(filename, mode))        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import fileinput

    f = fileinput.input(files='file.txt', openhook=fileinput_hook)

    for line in f:
        print(f.filename() + ": " + str(f.filelineno()) + ": " + line)
```

Note that I follow this reasonning (I might be wrong about the way to
do):

1. I try to create a generator (`tab_filter`) that is able to
   transform any tabulation by 8 whitespaces.
2. Then, I create a wrapper that can take a generator/iterator and
   pretend it is a normal file (`IterStream`).
3. I add a few cosmetic changes to make it easier to manipulate
   filters (the `@streamfilter` decorator).
4. I finally create a `fileinput_hook()` function intended to hook
   over the file inside the `fileinput` object.

Once everything done, I just have to create a `fileinput` object and
browse through it.

Unfornately, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 60, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/fileinput.py", line 265, in __next__
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/fileinput.py", line 370, in readline
    self._buffer = self._file.readlines(self._bufsize)
  File "./example.py", line 36, in readlines
    return self.read(size)
  File "./example.py", line 23, in read
    chunk = self.iterator.next()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

So, what did I do wrong, and how to achieve what I want? Am I really
far? Is there better ways to do it?

**EDIT** After solving my confusion between `__next__` and `next`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 63, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/fileinput.py", line 265, in __next__
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/fileinput.py", line 370, in readline
    self._buffer = self._file.readlines(self._bufsize)
  File "./example.py", line 39, in readlines
    return self.read(size)
  File "./example.py", line 26, in read
    chunk = self.__next__()
ValueError: I/O operation on uninitialized object
```

**EDIT2**

In fact, it works as AlokThakur said... I do not know what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python 3.x then you should use
 `__next__()` instead of next()

Change

```
self.iterator.next()
```

to

```
self.iterator.__next__()
```

Comment: Right... Stupid me... It solved the problem and lead me to another problem. The program now raises: ValueError: I/O operation on uninitialized object. I do not know if it worth submitting another question or not...

Comment: On which line?, Your code working for me after that small change

Comment: I just copy pasted your latest code and obviously changed the file name, It worked for me

Comment: I need to investigate further then... Anyway, thanks a lot for your time !